# How do I stop the 302 url redirection in a simple web crawl?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, httpresponse, http-status-code-302

I am trying to crawl a website using the Requests library in Python, and when I try:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.cell.com/cell-stem-cell/home', allow_redirects = False)
>>> r.status_code
302
>>> r.text
'The URL has moved <a href="https://secure.jbs.elsevierhealth.com/action/getSharedSiteSession?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cell.com%2Fcell-stem-cell%2Fhome&rc=0&code=cell-site">here</a>\n'
```

and when I try:

```
>>> r = requests.get("https://secure.jbs.elsevierhealth.com/action/getSharedSiteSession?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cell.com%2Fcell-stem-cell%2Fhome&rc=0&code=cell-site")
>>>
>>> r.text
'\n\n\n\n\n<style type="text/css">\n    .hidden {\n        display: none;\n        visibility: hidden;\n    }\n</style>\n\n<!-- hidden iFrame for each of the SSO URLs -->\n<div class="hidden">\n    \n        <iframe src="//acw.secure.jbs.elsevierhealth.com/SSOCore/update?utt=81c120bb854495181ef4ef3f679b12261e956c5-JKh">Your browser doesn\'t support iFrames!</iframe>\n    \n        <iframe src="//acw.sciencedirect.com/SSOCore/update?utt=81c120bb854495181ef4ef3f679b12261e956c5-JKh">Your browser doesn\'t support iFrames!</iframe>\n    \n        <iframe src="//acw.scopus.com/SSOCore/update?utt=81c120bb854495181ef4ef3f679b12261e956c5-JKh">Your browser doesn\'t support iFrames!</iframe>\n    \n        <iframe src="//acw.sciverse.com/SSOCore/update?utt=81c120bb854495181ef4ef3f679b12261e956c5-JKh">Your browser doesn\'t support iFrames!</iframe>\n    \n        <iframe src="//acw.mendeley.com/SSOCore/update?utt=81c120bb854495181ef4ef3f679b12261e956c5-JKh">Your browser doesn\'t support iFrames!</iframe>\n    \n        <iframe src="//acw.elsevier.com/SSOCore/update?utt=81c120bb854495181ef4ef3f679b12261e956c5-JKh">Your browser doesn\'t support iFrames!</iframe>\n    \n</div>\n\n\n\n<noscript>\n    <a href="CANT POST LINK BECAUSE OF LACK OF REPUTATION POINTS OF STACK OVERFLOW">Redirect</a>\n</noscript>\n\n<!-- redirect to the product page after all iFrames are rendered -->\n<script>\n    setTimeout(redirectFun,2000);\n    var iFramesList = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");\n    var renderedIFramesCount = 0;\n    var numberOfIFrames = iFramesList.length;\n    for (var i = 0; i < iFramesList.length; i++) {\n        var iFrame = iFramesList[i];\n        bindEvent(iFrame, \'load\', function(){\n            renderedIFramesCount = renderedIFramesCount + 1;\n            if (renderedIFramesCount >= numberOfIFrames)\n            {\n                redirectFun();\n            }\n        });\n    }\n    var doRedirect = true;\n    function redirectFun() {\n        if (doRedirect)\n            window.location.href = "CANT POST THIS WEBSITE BECAUSE OF MY REPUTATION POINTS ON STACKOVERFLOW";\n        doRedirect = false;\n    }\n\n    function bindEvent(el, eventName, eventHandler) {\n        if (el.addEventListener){\n            el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false);\n        } else if (el.attachEvent){\n            el.attachEvent(eventName, eventHandler);\n        }\n    }\n</script>\n\n'
```

I just want to get the HTML of the original website.

Comment: note: the r.text reads: The URL has moved here\n , with an "a href" to the link in the second get request

Comment: Try using selenium. It simulates a browser so it may not have this problem.

Comment: I think your problem is not a 302 redirect problem. it's more like a scraping authentication problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send User-agent along request headers to make the website to believe that the request is coming from a real web browser. So if you want the content of non-redirected url your code should be

```
from requests import get
content = get('http://www.cell.com/cell-stem-cell/home', headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36
 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'},allow_redirects = False).content
print content
```

The output will be:

```
The URL has moved <a href="https://secure.jbs.elsevierhealth.com/action/getShar
edSiteSession?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cell.com%2Fcell-stem-cell%2Fhome&rc=0&co
de=cell-site">here</a>
```

If you want the content of the redirected url then allows redirect, but include user-agent header. This method works for most of the websites that don't use dynamic content on their website. If you want to crawl data from a dynamic content website then you have to use web browser simulators like [selinium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: that definitely makes sense but could you expand on "If you want the content of the redirected url then allows redirect, but include user-agent header. ", please?

Comment: If you want data from the redirected url then your request should be `content= get('http://www.cell.com/cell-stem-cell/home', headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36
 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}).content` where content will have the html source of redirected url. By default requests handles redirection hence `allow_redirects =True` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

you just need little work around to get that directly. Server sends a Location header when redirection is required. you just need to access the URL in that Location header.

```
r = requests.get('http://www.cell.com/cell-stem-cell/home')
if r.status_code==302:
    r1 = requests.get(r.headers['Location'])
```

you will have your required data in `r1.content` or `r1.text`

Comment: In order to handle all redirection in the above code you can check like this. `if r.status_code/100==3:` so this will work for all redirection like 300,301,303,304,....